# How to find degree of fit in Kmeans++ clustering in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

How to find degree of fit in K-means++ clustering such that it shows how much percentage the inputs are aligned to each clusters. For instance, input A is in cluster 1 for 0.4 and in cluster 2 for 0.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard k-means is a *hard clustering* algorithm, i.e. there is no degree of fit; data points belong to one and only one cluster. Here is a quote from a relevant [academic paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0888613X12001739) (emphasis added):

> 2.3.1. *Hard k-means*
>
> [...]
>
> In k-means clustering only bivalent membership degrees of object *i* to
>   cluster *k* are allowed: λ[i,k]∈{0,1}. If an object *i* is a member of a
>   cluster **it cannot be a member of any other cluster**

[K-means++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B) is just an algorithm for choosing the initial values (seeds) for k-means, and it does not change the fundamental character of k-means as a hard clustering algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

There are "soft" *variants* of k-means that allow this.

In particular, fuzzy-c-means (don't ask me why they use c instead of k...)

But beware that the resulting soft assignment is far from a statistical probability. It's just a number that gives some relative weight based on the squared distance, *without* any strong statistical model.